# Missing Template Error when I render a partial from one controller in the action of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am pretty new to rails and mvc, but my application has users and I want to allow someone to quickly sign up from the home page using a bootstrap modal and to allow them to sign up through a normal sign up page.

In my Users controller I have created a partial for the modal `_newUserModal.html.erb` and I want to use this in the index action from my Home controller.

I have read that I should load partials from another controller inside the action. So I am trying the following

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render 'users/newUserModal'
  end
end
```

This is giving me the error

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template users/newUserModal with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>   * "/home/jeff/Development/iHaul/app/views" * "/home/jeff/Development/iHaul" * "/"

I have a feeling I am missing something small but I can't figure it out.

Ok by moving the render to the bottom of my home.html.erb it has allowed my code to work. I know this isn't the best practice but it works for now. If anyone can shed some light on the issue that would help a lot.

My advice for anyone who is using partials from another controller is do not give a partial the same name as a method. If you do you have to specifically tell render to use the partial file with

```
render :partial => 'controller/action'
```

if your careful render works normally, although the above is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my remaining question is wrong. After a nights sleep I realized I am not using the MVC pattern for what it is designed for. I was being to precious with using @user = User.new . If I just use that in the index function of my home controller everything works beautifully.